# Append timestamp to kubernetes --watch-only command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm running a Kubernetes job, where I want to monitor the state. I'm running various `--watch-only` commands simultaneously, e.g
`kubectl get pods --watch-only`, which shows me the updated state of pods. But, I want to have *timestamp* and some *string* appended to the output.

The idea is to know when the state changed and also add additional info as a string.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello. `kubectl get pods --watch-only` command has no builtin options to add the information like timestamps and others. Have you considered using `$ kubectl logs` where your application adds this data for you? Also have you checked `$ kubectl describe RESOURCE_NAME` with their state statuses (started/finished).

Comment: this is what i found working so far ```kubectl get pods --watch-only | while read line ; do echo -e "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")\t pods\t $line" ; done```

Answer (score 8):

Giving more visibility to the potential solution for the question posted in the comments by original poster:

> This is what i found working so far kubectl get pods --watch-only | while read line ; do echo -e "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")\t pods\t $line" ; done

Command used:

- `$ kubectl get pods --watch-only | while read line ; do echo -e "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")\t pods\t $line" ; done`

Solution is correct but the changes in state (`PENDING`,`RUNNING`,`SUCCEEDED/COMPLETED`) would need to be further extracted (assuming further actions) from the above command.

---

Looking on this from a different perspective you can use the [official Kubernetes API library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to monitor the statuses of pods and jobs and act accordingly to them (for example: do something when job succeeded).

---

I've created an **example** app with Kubernetes Python API library to watch the statuses of pods and jobs.

Assuming that:

- You have a working Kubernetes cluster with `kubectl` configured
- You have installed Python and required library:

  - `$ pip install kubernetes`

Using the example for a `Job`:

> *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)*

#### Example for pods

Below is the sample code in Python3 that would watch for pods and print a message when status of pod is set to `Succeeded`:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
from datetime import datetime

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
w = watch.Watch()
for event in w.stream(v1.list_namespaced_pod, namespace="default", watch=False):
    print("POD_NAME: " + event['object'].metadata.name) # print the name
    print("TIME: " + str(datetime.now())) # print the time 
    print("PHASE: " +  event['object'].status.phase) # print the status of the pod
    print("CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!")

    if (event['object'].status.phase == "Succeeded") and (event['type'] != "DELETED"): # do below when condition is met 
        print ("----> This pod succeeded, do something here!")
    print("---")
```

This would produce an output similar to one below:

```sh
POD_NAME: pi-pjmm5
TIME: 2020-09-06 15:28:01.541244
PHASE: Pending
CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!
---
POD_NAME: pi-pjmm5
TIME: 2020-09-06 15:28:03.894063
PHASE: Running
CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!
---
POD_NAME: pi-pjmm5
TIME: 2020-09-06 15:28:09.044219
PHASE: Succeeded
CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!
----> This pod succeeded, do something here!
---
```

#### Example for jobs

Below is the sample code in Python3 that would watch for jobs and print a message when status of job is set to `Succeeded`:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
from datetime import datetime

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.BatchV1Api()
w = watch.Watch()
for event in w.stream(v1.list_namespaced_job, namespace="default", watch=False):
    print("JOB_NAME: " + event['object'].metadata.name)
    print("TIME: " + str(datetime.now()))
    print("STATUS: " + event['type'])
    print("CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!")

    if (event['object'].status.succeeded == 1) and (event['type'] != "DELETED"): 
        print ("----> This job succeeded, do something here!")
    print("---")
```

This would produce an output similar to one below:

```sh
JOB_NAME: pi
TIME: 2020-09-06 15:32:49.909096
STATUS: ADDED
CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!
---
JOB_NAME: pi
TIME: 2020-09-06 15:32:49.936856
STATUS: MODIFIED
CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!
---
JOB_NAME: pi
TIME: 2020-09-06 15:32:56.998511
STATUS: MODIFIED
CUSTOM AMAZING TEXT HERE!
----> This job succeeded, do something here!
---
```

Answer (score 1):

`ts` ( from [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) ) or [`gnomon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gnomon) ( from `npm i -g gnomon` ) helps for standard timestamp output:

i.e.:

- `ts`:

  ```bash
  $ kubectl get po -w | ts -i
  00:00:00 NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  00:00:00 jenkins-0   2/2     Running   1661       55d
  00:00:57 jenkins-0   1/2     OOMKilled   1661       55d
  00:00:15 jenkins-0   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1661       55d
  00:04:49 jenkins-0   2/2     Running            1662       55d
  00:02:19 jenkins-0   1/2     OOMKilled          1662       55d
  00:00:15 jenkins-0   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1662       55d
  ```
- `gnomon`:

  ```bash
  $ kubectl get po -w | gnomon
     0.0234s   NAME        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
  287.3296s   jenkins-0   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1660       55d
  158.1299s   jenkins-0   2/2     Running            1661       55d
    14.4898s   jenkins-0   1/2     OOMKilled          1661       55d
  130.1794s   jenkins-0   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1661       55d
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you want, but if you're okay with JSON output, piping the `kubectl` output to `jq` works well and is concise.

```
kubectl get pods \
    -o json \
    --watch-only \
| jq '.time = (now | todate)'
```

If you want to customize the time string, you can replace `todate` with something like `strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")`

Answer (score -1):

There is `--timestamps` for that:

```
kubectl logs -f --timestamps ...
```

Comment: The question relates to the `kubectl get` command, which doesn't support the `--timestamps` flag.