# How can I see the history of ready condition changes?

Tags: kubernetes

You can get events with `Readiness probe failed ...` but there are two problems with this:

1. a readiness probe fail doesn't mean that the pod becomes not-ready since it may require more than one probe fail (`readinessProbe.failureThreshold`)
2. k8s will aggregate / summarize them these events making it almost impossible to understand and debug specific cases

Is there a way to get this information with (`kubectl` and co) and without development code (like a custom resource)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, you won't be able to find Kubernetes `events` for pods becoming ready or not ready, because the status change is not an event, just an update made by Kubelet :/

The probes itself are indeed [issuing events](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.28.0/pkg/kubelet/prober/prober.go#L100-L117), but as you've mentioned these are just "Readiness probe failed" logs, that you can't really use. As a side note, even if you were able to use these events, you will be limited by the fact Kubernetes [does not emit events when readiness probe succeeds](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.28.0/pkg/kubelet/prober/prober.go#L116).

Anyway, there are 3 ways (probably more, but this should be enough here) to find out when `Ready` condition changes.

#### Watch your pod(s) conditions with kubectl

This requires to have a script running while your pod is running. With `kubectl`:

```bash
kubectl get pods -n default name-of-my-pod --watch-only --no-headers \
   -o jsonpath='{"Ready="}{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}{"\n"}' | \
   while read line ; \
   do \
     echo -e "$(date --rfc-3339=ns) $line" ; \
   done
```

The first part will watch the pod named `name-of-my-pod` and only outputs the `Ready` condition status. The second part of the script is to add a timestamp as prefix, as `kubectl ... --watch` does not provide an option to print timestamps for now ([more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774000)).

The result will look like this:

```
2023-08-21 16:28:20.866158908+02:00 Ready=True
2023-08-21 16:28:21.579293747+02:00 Ready=False
2023-08-21 16:28:24.592714416+02:00 Ready=True
2023-08-21 16:28:27.562872181+02:00 Ready=False
```

Obviously, you can follow the pod status in real-time, but if the script exits, you won't be able to find the history. But it should be enough for most real-time debugging use cases.

#### Parse kubelet logs

This requires to first add more verbosity to kubelet logs (with `--v=3` option). Once done, after retrieving kubelet logs, you'll be able to find the info about the status of the pod by looking at the `Status for pod updated successfully` logs:

```bash
cat kubelet.log | \
  grep 'pod="default/name-of-my-pod"' | \
  grep 'Status for pod updated successfully' | \
  sed 's~\(.\{15\}\).*Ready:\(true\|false\).*~\1 Ready=\2~'
```

The parsing command works for Kubernetes 1.25.3, but it can evolve in the future, and parsing with `grep` and `sed` makes this very fragile (e.g. as of now, the first 15 characters is the date, but what if that changes someday?).

Anyway, the result will look like this:

```
Aug 21 14:28:20 Ready=true
Aug 21 14:28:21 Ready=false
Aug 21 14:28:24 Ready=true
Aug 21 14:28:27 Ready=false
```

The main advantage over the `kubectl` solution is that you can find the history, and don't need to run a script in the background.

#### Use a dedicated monitoring tool

The most robust solution is to use a dedicated monitoring tool, like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), to scrape your Kubernetes cluster metrics. You'll probably need this anyway in the future for other debugging needs, so better use it right now for your use-case. If you have it already installed, great! Otherwise, this [Helm chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/kube-prometheus-stack-48.3.2/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) can help you install it very quickly.

The `kube_pod_status_ready` metric in [`kube-state-metrics` pod metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/v2.9.2/docs/pod-metrics.md) should be enough. As long as you have a short `scrape_interval` configured for Prometheus, you should be able to see every change of your pod `Ready` condition.

The following PromQL query:

```
kube_pod_status_ready{namespace="default", pod="name-of-my-pod", condition="true"}
```

will give you the following result:

[image: PromQL query result to retrieve the pod Ready status]

When `value = 1`, the pod is ready; otherwise, it's not ready.

Here, my scrape interval is 1s, so I have a less than 1s delay between the pod passes ready and the scrape. But if you have a scrape interval of 30s, be careful that the moment it shows ready/not-ready in the graph is probably not the exact moment it has passed ready/not-ready.

Also, with Prometheus, you'll be able to retrieve the status in the past (depending of your configuration and retention of metrics).